# How can we run the pipeline and PBI dashboard and take the PBI dashboard screenshot and send that screenshot to some people

Tags: power-automate

Basically we need to automate the process of pipeline run and dashboard refresh and mailing .after dashboard refresh we need take the screenshot of dashboard and send that screenshot to people's using power automate.
We need to use pipeline runs dashboard refresh and send mails with screenshot all end to end process will need to implement using power automate is these possibile?